# Is uri validation really important in Zend_Http_Client?

Tags: php, security, url, zend-framework, web-crawler

I am using Zend_Http_Client (Zend Framework 1) to crawl some data from web.
Before request, Zend_Http_Client validates given URI by Zend_Uri::validate().
The validation rules in Zend_Uri::validate() are very strict, so i can't grab a lot of pages.
Eg.

- http://www.investing.com/central-banks/european-central-bank/speeches/euro-banknotes-€-a-means-of-payment-recognised-worldwide-213287 - because of €
- http://forum.cyanogenmod.pl/index.php/user/19228-łukasz-lech - because of polish letter ł
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/bruno-magli/RUgdzh7fqhw/DK_lGZi6xq8J - because of #

I tried to add this special chars to Zend_Uri rules, but there is so many special chars, that i would prefer to disable the whole validation process in Zend_Uri. Maybe such solution isn't elegant, but i don't know why Zend forces me to validate URI...

My concern is: can it be insecure, if i use zend_http_client without URI validation to grab html from unverified URIs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use eg your own class which extends **Zend_Http_Client**.

Just use your own Uri Object and redeclare **setUri** and **getUri** and **request**.

The Header **Host:** part should get manually set in the options, i guess there is no need for a Zend_Uri if this header is set in options array.

But maybe you just have not used Zend_Uri or Zend_Client_Http the right way.

As a not valid Zend_Uri is not valid at all.

You can try doing the same thing your browser does when sending the url from the browser address bar to the server, it **urlencode** the url...

So, a sign like **€** would become:

```
http://www.investing.com/.../euro-banknotes-%E2%82%AC-a-means-of-payment-recognised-worldwide-213287
```

The **€** sign would become the encoded value **%E2%82%AC**.

Most browsers today wont change the url, as most users wont understand why their url changed.

Some crazy browsers start only showing the domain of a webpage in their browser address bar, like mobile safari or chrome.

**Try just to urlencode your url before sending it to Zend_Http_Client and I guess you will be fine with valid Uri instances of Zend_Uri!**

```
$url = urlencode($url);

$client = new Zend_Http_Client($url);

$response = $client->request(Zend_Http_Client::GET);
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Let's first look at what's happening when you pass a URL *string* to Zend_Http_Client:

1. Zend_Http_Client::__construct() passes the URL to Zend_Http_Client::setUri()
2. Zend_Http_Client::setUri() passes the URL to Zend_Uri::factory()
3. Zend_Uri::factory() calls Zend_Uri_Http::__construct()
4. Zend_Uri_Http::__construct() calls Zend_Uri_Http::valid()
5. Zend_Uri_Http::valid() calls multiple Zend_Uri_Http::validate*() methods

However, passing an instance of Zend_Uri_Http to Zend_Http_Client will cause setUri() to clone and use it instead, so **one can skip Zend_Uri's validation by creating a URI class and passing an instance of it to Zend_Http_Client**.

Create a URI class that extends Zend_Uri_Http and overwrite the properties and methods (but not the constants, more below) necessary for your situation:

```
class My_Uri_Http extends Zend_Uri_Http
{
    public function valid()
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    // or

    public function validatePath($path = null)
    {
        $this->_regex['path'] = '...';
        return parent::validatePath($path);
    }
}
```

Then tell Zend_Uri::factory()'s to use your class and pass the result (an instance of My_Uri_Http and Zend_Uri_Http by extension) to Zend_Http_Client:

```
$uri = Zend_Uri::factory($url, 'My_Uri_Http');

$client = new Zend_Http_Client($uri);
```

**Why not the constants?**

Zend_Uri_Http::__construct() uses self::CONSTANT to create the regular expressions it uses in its validate*() methods.  Overwriting those constants in My_Uri_Http will have no effect because self:: references Zend_Uri_Http.  (You could ovewrite the constants in child classes if static:: was used instead.)